# how to sync keychain passwords from one iPhone (organizer) with a family member’s iPhone (member) that has a different iCloud account?

Tags: icloud, password, keychain, family-sharing

how to sync keychain passwords with another keychain? I tried setting my husbands new iPhone 12 using my iCloud info and after inputting his personal details, the info on my iPhone 8 changed to his info. So I created an iCloud email for the iPhone 12 and added my spouse on the family sharing. My question is how do I sync my keychain Passwords from the iPhone 8 with my husband iCloud accounts so he’ll be able to autofill passwords?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sync keychain passwords across accounts.

You can easily and securely AirDrop a password from the passwords screen in settings to share it with other people.